# Inner class : Attempt to de-reference a null object

Tags: class, error, inner

when i try to add "respDetail" to "response" i get the error "Attempt to de-reference a null object", 
any idee ? thank you

```
public with sharing class Process_WSI {
    public class Detail {
        public String field;
        public String errName;
    }
    public List<Detail> details;
    public String code;
    public String message;

    public static Process_WSI parse(String json) {
        return (Process_WSI) System.JSON.deserialize(json, Process_WSI.class);
    }
}
```

Call

```
Process_WSI response = new Process_WSI();
Process_WSI.Detail respDetail = new Process_WSI.Detail();

respDetail.field= 'myField';
respDetail.errName= 'Error Txt must ....';

response.message = 'Error';
response.code = '999';
response.details.add(respDetail);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the apex class, the list variable `List<Detail> details` has not been initialized.

You could either replace that code with `public List<Detail> details = new List<Detail>();`
or
Initialize the list in the calling code as `response.details = new List<Process_WSI.Detail>();` just before the last line.

Answer (score 1):

You also have to allocate memory to "details" variable which you can do by either creating a constructor in the class

```
 public Process_WSI(){
        details = new List<Details>();
    }
```

or just do it there it self

```
public List<Details> details= new List<Details>();
```